# multiple extract() with WHERE clause possible?

Tags: date

So far I have come up with the below:

```
WHERE (extract(month FROM orders)) = 
                     (SELECT min(extract(month from orderdate))
                     FROM orders)
```

However, that will consequently return zero to many rows, and in my case, many, because many orders exist within that same earliest (minimum) month, i.e. 4th February, 9th February, 15th Feb, ...

I know that a `WHERE` clause can contain multiple columns, so why wouldn't the below work?

```
WHERE (extract(day FROM orderdate)), (extract(month FROM orderdate)) = 
                     (SELECT min(extract(day from orderdate)), min(extract(month FROM orderdate))
                     FROM orders)
```

I simply get: `SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Any help would be great, thank you!

Sample data:
02-Feb-2012
14-Feb-2012
22-Dec-2012
09-Feb-2013
18-Jul-2013
01-Jan-2014

Output:
02-Feb-2012
14-Feb-2012

Desired output:
02-Feb-2012

Comment: _WHERE clause can contain multiple columns_ that's only valid for a subquery, afaik

Comment: I don't understand the requirement from your description, can you post a small set of sample data along with an expected output?

Comment: Sure, sorry about the confusion. Added in OP. (Sorry about the formatting... not sure how to deal with that)

Comment: Not sure I follow still... if you had a row with 01-Jan-2014, that would be picked ahead of 02-Feb-2012? Is that really what you want? I'm struggling to see why you don't just want the earliest date.

Comment: @Restricted - cleaning up comments is fine, but you've removed one that clarified your example; can you fix the output and desired output so it shows you want 01-Jan-2014 as the result, otherwise the answers don't make sense? You've also removed all the context; some description of how you get to that answer would still be helpful for someone finding this question in the future - particularly the odd rules you have, as someone reading this would assume you still want the year involved.

Comment: My apologies, I agree. However, what do you mean by changing the desired output to 01-Jan-2014? The desired output should be as delineated in the OP, 02-Feb-2012.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your table and found out you just messed up the brackets a bit. The following works for me:

```
where
    (extract(day from OrderDate),extract(month from OrderDate))
    =
    (select
        min(extract(day from OrderDate)),
        min(extract(month from OrderDate))
     from orders
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. However, with multiple extract(), I encounter "no rows selected". I have no idea why, and it looks like I have to go about it another way...

Comment: See the comment from Eat a Peach below: "Fetching min day and month separately isnt correct. For example, if u have 10th Jan and 3rd Feb as dates, you will get 3rd Jan as result, which is clearly wrong." You will have to first select min month and then the min day for this month, not overall min month and min day. But you requested something different.

Comment: Right, I see. So having to incorporate multiple subquery nests, that would make the entire statement look quite convoluted though wouldn't it? Put simply, I wanted to keep it simple with basic SQL commands, is that still possible?

Comment: It's probably still possible using extract, but could get ugly. Alex Poole's answer looks simple and solves the problem. Using CTEs like my other answer is possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        extract(month from OrderDate) date_month,
        extract(day from OrderDate) date_day,
        OrderNo
    from tablename
), cte2 as (
    select min(date_month) min_date_month, min(date_day) min_date_day
    from cte1
)
select cte1.*
from cte1
where (date_month, date_day) = (select min_date_month, min_date_day from cte2)
```

A common table expression enables you to restructure your data and then use this data to do your select. The first cte-block (cte1) selects the month and the day for each of your table rows. Cte2 then selects min(month) and min(date). The last select then combines both ctes to select all rows from cte1 that have the desired month and day.

There is probably a shorter solution to that, however I like common table expressions as they are almost all the time better to understand than the "optimal, shortest" query.

Comment: I don't know about the multiple extract functions, I usually like to avoid complex, hard-to-read stuff like that and replace it by something which is easy-to-understand, even though it is probably more writing. I added a bit of explanation. If you need more help, please supply full table structure and I will give you a final query.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by the full table structure. i.e. the attribute names and specified data types? I'm not sure what else to add but it is simply a table (called Orders), with 2 attributes. OrderNO, OrderDate, with Number and Date as their data types respectively. I doubt you were referring to the actual table data, however if you do require that, please let me know. I appreciate the assistance Thomas. Also, I would prefer not to use cte if that is OK, perhaps some time in the future.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the column names.There would be one more approach I could suggest. You could simply do `month * 100 + day` and use this "virtual" column to order your rows.

Comment: Fetching min day and month separately isnt correct. For example, if u have 10th Jan and 3rd Feb as dates, you will get 3rd Jan as result, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If that is really what you want, as bizarre as it seems, then as a different approach you could forget the extracts and the subquery against the table to get the minimums, and use an analytic approach instead:

```
select orderdate
from (
  select o.*,
    row_number() over (order by to_char(orderdate, 'MMDD')) as rn
  from orders o
)
where rn = 1;

ORDERDATE
---------
01-JAN-14
```

The `row_number()` effectively adds a pseudo-column to every row in your original table, based on the month and day in the order date. The `rn` values are unique, so there will be one row marked as 1, which will be from the earliest day in the earliest month. If you have multiple orders with the same day/month, say 01-Jan-2013 and 01-Jan-2014, then you'll still only get exactly one with `rn = 1`, but which is picked is indeterminate. You'd need to add further `order by` conditions to make it deterministic, but I have no idea what you might want.

That is done in the inner query; the outer query then filters so that only the records marked with `rn = 1` is returned; so you get exactly one row back from the overall query.

This also avoids the situation where the earliest day number is not in the earliest month number - say if you only had 01-Jan-2014 and 02-Feb-2014; comparing the day and month separately would look for 01-Feb-2014, which doesn't exist.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2ac8/1) (with Thomas Tschernich's anwer thrown in too, giving the same result for this data).

---

To join the result against your invoice table, you don't need to join to the orders table again - especially not with a cross join, which is skewing your results. You can do the join (at least) two ways:

```
SELECT 
    o.orderno,
        to_char(o.orderdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
    i.invno
FROM 
  (
    SELECT o.*,
        row_number() over (order by to_char(orderdate, 'MMDD')) as rn
    FROM orders o
  ) o, invoices i
WHERE i.invno = o.invno
AND rn = 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
    o.orderno,
        to_char(o.orderdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
    i.invno
FROM 
  (
    SELECT orderno, orderdate, invno
    FROM
      (
        SELECT o.*,
            row_number() over (order by to_char(orderdate, 'MMDD')) as rn
        FROM orders o
      )
    WHERE rn = 1
  ) o, invoices i
WHERE i.invno = o.invno;
```

The first looks like it does more work but the execution plans are the same.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4b01/4) with your pastebin-supplied query that gets two rows back, and these two that get one.

Comment: OK, reluctantly changed the answer and SQL Fiddle to old-style joins. Your cross join was doing nothing useful and just duplicating rows. I kept the inner join between the inline view against `objects` and `invoices`; it's just the extra cross-joined `orders` that was a problem.

Comment: Righteo, that makes sense - perfect. Thanks for baring with me Alex. Glad this community have such extremely helpful people. Have a great day, cheers.